# iOS Facebook Login "object nil" crash

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

Working with Facebook 3.7 for iOS, authentication for App.  It works 70% of the time, other 30% crashes.  Seems to have no bearing on whether connected in internet.  In the first method below - populateUserDetails, I check whether dictionary is nil, which I would think would stop this issue, back it still happens.

Here is my error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: 0_auth_logger_id)'
```

Here is my authentication code:

```
- (void)populateUserDetails
{
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
       NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
       NSError *error) {
         if (!error || ![user isEqualToDictionary: nil]) {
             // if (!error) {
             self.userNameLabel.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
             email = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
             //      self.userProfileImage.profileID = user.id;

             if ([facebookUser isEqualToString:@"yes"]){
             [self appendAndSaveData];
             [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIntroScreenLogin" sender:self];
             }

         }
     }];
}
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
[self populateUserDetails];
}
}

-(void)logoutButtonWasPressed:(id)sender {
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}


- (IBAction)performLogin:(id)sender
{
 facebookUser = @"yes";
 NSLog(@"IntroScreen, email: %@", email);
 AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
 [appDelegate openSession];

    if([email length] >0){

     [self appendAndSaveData];
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIntroScreenLogin" sender:self];
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

While there appear to be no references in your code to setting values in an NSMutableDictionary, the terminating message is probably referring to the fact you cannot pass nil as a key to the setObject:forKey: method. It would help to post a stack trace but in that absence, look for calls to setObject:forKey and verify that the forKey argument is non-nil.

Comment: That helps.  I think my appears to be from clicking the IBAction more than once before the session could be opened. If I give it time, it seems to work fine.  I included a spinner to signal that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open in your favorite editor:

   ```
   [facebook_sdk_folder]/src/FBSession.m
   ```

around line 930-940 you'll find the following code

```
if (permissions != nil) {
  NSString* scope = [permissions componentsJoinedByString:@","];
  [params setValue:scope forKey:@"scope"];
}
```

change it to

```
if (permissions != nil) {
  NSString* scope = [permissions componentsJoinedByString:@","];
  if( scope )  // << add this line
    [params setValue:scope forKey:@"scope"];
}
```

then rebuild the framework again

```
[facebook_sdk_folder]/scripts/build_framework.sh
```

(make sure that newly generated framework which is in [facebook_sdk_folder]/build/FacebookSDK.framework is the one included in your project)

Comment: How do you access the code from the SDK? Nevermind.. https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/